# codeigniter doctrine getRepository() working on local but not on server

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-3

I am user CodeIgniter 3 and Doctrine2. Now, when I tried to find record it works on my local server but its not woking on my web server; here is my **find** code

> $user = $this->em->getRepository('entities\AdminAuth')->findBy(
>   array(
>               'username'    => $data['username'],           'password' => $pwd
>           )
>       );

Its showed me following error on my web server,

> **An uncaught Exception was encountered**
>
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Access to undeclared static property: Modules::$loader
>
> Filename:
>   /home/tiffintom/public_html/mgt/Master_Panel/application/third_party/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php
>
> Line Number: 228
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   /home/tiffintom/public_html/mgt/Master_Panel/application/third_party/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php
>   Line: 904 Function: classExists
>
> File:
>   /home/tiffintom/public_html/mgt/Master_Panel/application/third_party/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php
>   Line: 189 Function: validateAssocations
>
> File:
>   /home/tiffintom/public_html/mgt/Master_Panel/application/third_party/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php
>   Line: 171 Function: validateRuntimeMetadata
>
> File:
>   /home/tiffintom/public_html/mgt/Master_Panel/application/third_party/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php
>   Line: 302 Function: doLoadMetadata
>
> File:
>   /home/tiffintom/public_html/mgt/Master_Panel/application/third_party/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php
>   Line: 205 Function: loadMetadata
>
> File:
>   /home/tiffintom/public_html/mgt/Master_Panel/application/third_party/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php
>   Line: 268 Function: getMetadataFor
>
> File:
>   /home/tiffintom/public_html/mgt/Master_Panel/application/third_party/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php
>   Line: 682 Function: getClassMetadata
>
> File:
>   /home/tiffintom/public_html/mgt/Master_Panel/application/modules/admin/controllers/Authentication.php
>   Line: 21 Function: getRepository
>
> File: /home/tiffintom/public_html/mgt/Master_Panel/index.php Line: 322
>   Function: require_once**

Please help me

Comment: may be because of  filename case sensitive mismatch on server , double check your file name for case

Comment: checked it..but still not working

Answer (score 0):

It was happening for the version of the doctrine classLoader. I used old version classLoader from my previous project thats why it was showing error.